# How to check if ParseObject contains particular column in database (Parse Dashboard)?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to check if item has particular column in database. I'm using Parse Dashboard and value in this column is type `String` and there is not empty string but `(undefined)`. And this is returning null value. So I want to check if actual column does exist.
So I've used `ParseObject.containsKey("column_name")`, but this is returning `false`. I know, that value in this column is empty/null, but I want to check not value, but if that column actually exist before I can put something there.

According to documentation, this function should do exactly what I want, but it obviously doesnt work.

I've checked `objectId` of this item and I've checked this item in database and object with this exact id is in Class table which contains column with exact name.

Documentation:

https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-dotNET/api/html/M_Parse_ParseObject_ContainsKey.htm

Comment: I'm guessing you are using mongodb?

Comment: Nope it's called Parse Dashboard

Comment: The documentation refers to .NET. your tag refers to android. What programming language is this?

Comment: I'm using this in Android App. It's same for Android Doc: https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/ (in ParseObject part -> containsKey() method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `containsKey` method on a `ParseObject` will tell you only if a value has been set for that instance, not if the class can accept that property.  What you want to do is inspect the Schema.

Operations on the schema (including reading) require the master key, so it is not appropriate for a client SDK like Android to access the schema directly.

I don't know your use case, as it seems unlikely that your clients would need to know this, but if you wanted a client to know the answer, you'd have to set up a [cloud function](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions) that could use the master key to [inspect the schema](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#schema).